# Why can the objective function equal to the sum of squared distances from a point to several others not have local minima that are not global minima?

Tags: calculus

A group of friends is planning to host a baby shower over the weekend. They want to find a location for the party that minimizes the sum of squared distances from their houses to the location of the party. Why is the following statement false: The optimization problem may have local minima that are not global minima? I do not know how this can be formally proven but my solution attempt is shown below.

Solution Attempt

There is a unique point that minimizes the objective function. If you move farther away from the point then the objective function would become larger and if you move closer it is closer to the optimum value. If a local minimum were to exist that would mean that although the distances from the unique point that minimizes the objective function can get bigger or smaller that point still is optimal for all x in a particular interval.

Comment: I posted an answer but deleted it when I realized you did not share any thoughts or solution attempts.

Comment: I have edited the question to include my attempt at a solution.

Comment: I think in your attempt you need to justify why if you move away from the global minimum the objective function becomes larger. Surely you may be moving *towards* one of the houses, thus that term in the square sum is getting smaller. Why can you claim that the overall sum won't get smaller too?

Comment: Some of the terms may get smaller but the overall sum would be larger because we know that there is a unique point that minimizes the objective function.

Comment: @Andrew this is not enough. The overall sum, in principle, can get larger and smaller and larger and smaller when you depart from the point of the overall minimum - as long as it never goes *below* the value of the overall minimum. So this argument does not work.

Comment: Is it correct that if you move away from the global minimum the objective function's value increases and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $(x,y)$ is the location of the party and $(x_i,y_i)$ are the locations of the houses, your objective function is
$$
f(x,y) = \sum_{i=1}^n (x-x_i)^2 + \sum_{i=1}^n(y-y_i)^2.
$$

Hence, the candidates to a minimum are the solutions of the system
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n 2(x-x_i)=0, \quad \sum_{i=1}^n 2(y-y_i)=0,
$$

which means that there is a single critical point, $(x,y)= \left(\frac 1n \sum x_i ,\frac 1n \sum y_i\right)$, that is actually the global minimizer.

Answer (score 1):

The square of a distance is (being a quadratic function) convex, and the sum of convex functions is also a convex function. Convex functions have a unique global minimum on convex domains (and the entire plane is a convex domain).